# jQuery Function to append input to form works in Chrome, but not Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery function:

```
$('.bid_btn').click(function(event) {
        var doctor_id = $(event.target).val();
        console.log(doctor_id);
        if(doctor_id == ""){
          console.log('nothing here');
        } else {
              if(!$('input[name="form_doctor_id"]').length){
                  $form.append($('<input type = "hidden" name = "form_doctor_id">').val(doctor_id));
              } else {
                  if(doctor_id == "Book Appointment"){
                    console.log('nothing to add here');
                  } else {
                    $('input[name="form_doctor_id"]').val(doctor_id);
                  }
                }
          }
      $(this).unbind(event);
    });
```

What it does is takes the value of a class of bid_btn any time a button with that class is clicked, and then appends it to a form as a hidden input. It works fine in Chrome, but it isn't working in Safari, and I can't figure out why. I've read some other similar questions about this sort of issue on Stack Overflow, but I am hoping someone will be able to help point out where in my jQuery function I can solve this.

Comment: Is this `button.bid_btn` contains any other HTML tags ?

Comment: yes, it's an html class, so there are multiple tags with it.

Comment: Try to change `$(event.target).val()` to `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH This solved my problem, thank you so much! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Again, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `event.target` to `this`. `this` always refers to the DOM element the listener was attached to, but `event.target` is the actual DOM element that was clicked, for example:

```
<button class="bid_btn" value="1"> <span> Icon </span> Button </button>
```

If you attach click listener:

```
$('.bid_btn').click(function(event) {...});
```

when you click the `span` then the handler will be invoked and the `event.target` is the span element which has no `value`.